Upgrade Error && Thegetter 'subtitle2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme' || Member not found: 'MediaQuery.boldTextOverride'. material theme
Upgrade Flutter to the latest version but got this issue. try to delete the Android folder and then recreate it with the help of the flutter create . command but this issue is still not solved. also, update the material theam for did not able to solve this.
already up to date

Error
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/dropdown_search-2.0.1/lib/dropdown_search.dart:491:46: Error: Thegetter 'subtitle2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart'
 ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle2'.
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/dropdown_search-2.0.1/lib/dropdown_search.dart:515:46: Error: Thegetter 'subtitle1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart'
 ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle1'.
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1);
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/dropdown_search-2.0.1/lib/src/popupMenu.dart:193:25: Error: The
getter 'subtitle1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart'
 ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle1'.
        theme.textTheme.subtitle1;
                        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/dropdown_search-2.0.1/lib/src/selection_widget.dart:221:31:
Error: No named parameter with the name 'isAlwaysShown'.
                              isAlwaysShown:
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scrollbar.dart:87:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments
don't match.
  const Scrollbar({
        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/dropdown_search-2.0.1/lib/src/selection_widget.dart:723:48:
Error: The getter 'subtitle1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart'
 ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'subtitle1'.
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fl_chart-0.55.2/lib/src/utils/utils.dart:257:20: Error: Member
not found: 'MediaQuery.boldTextOverride'.
    if (MediaQuery.boldTextOverride(context)) {
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


It looks like you are using an old version of dropdown_search. You are using version 2.0.1 while version 5.0.6 already exists. The version you are using uses code that is not compatible with the latest Flutter version. I don't know if the latest version of dropdown_search fixed this but it's worth a try to simply update the package. Another option is to downgrade your Flutter version to a version that is compatible with your current dropdown_search version.

thanks some issues are fixed but some issues are still available an this is:-
lib/utility/src.dart:3:1: Error: 'defaultScrollNotificationPredicate' is exported from both 'package:dropdown_search/src/properties/scrollbar_props.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_notification.dart'.
export 'package:flutter/material.dart';
^
/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fl_chart-0.55.2/lib/src/utils/utils.dart:257:20: Error: Member not found: 'MediaQuery.boldTextOverride'.
if (MediaQuery.boldTextOverride(context)) {
